# Chaining stateful predicates together

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I am trying to implement this definition:-

```
 def validate(validationPredicates: List[A => Try[Boolean]]): Try[Boolean] = ???
```

And the way its supposed to work is the follows:-

1. Accept a list of predicates (with different args for each predicate, so A is technically wrong).
2. Run through each of them. The methods that are put in here can either return true, false or throw an exception.
3. Stop the run through each of them when we either see a false, or see an exception in the sequence.

There are other things going on here (other kinds of side effects in the individual validators, but that will not impact the chain of operations).

Can someone tell me how to implement the chain AND the syntax for accepting functions of any input args but output always Try[Boolean]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but isn't this just

```
Try(validationPredicates.forall(_(a).get))
```

- If all predicates return `Success(true)` you will get `Success(true)`
- If any predicate returns `Success(false)` you will get `Success(false)` and no more predicates will be tested
- If any predicate returns `Failed(e)`, the `.get` will re-throw the exception which is caught by the outer Try and you will get `Failed(e)`

This assumes that the functions return `Try[Boolean]`. If they just return `Boolean` (as described in the text) then just remove the `.get`

I haven't addressed the remark about "the syntax for accepting functions of any input args" because I don't know what it means, and feels like a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

```
  def validate[A](validationPredicates: List[A => Try[Boolean]]): A => Try[Boolean] =
    (a: A) => validationPredicates.foldLeft(Try(true))(
        (state, predicate) => state.flatMap(bool => predicate(a).map(_ && bool))
      )
```

In cats world, you are looking for `traverse`

Comment: I think this is close, but will continue to execute predicates even if an earlier one returns false. This could cause later side-effects to still happen, which sounds like is not desired. I think you could fix it by replacing the inner `flatMap` with `bool => if (bool) predicate(a) else Try(false)`

Comment: This is classic problem with foldLeft, can't stop it early,  but your suggestion is a fine workaround